# Flex / Grid - 2 columns, but 1st column has 2 columns inside as well

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to achieve that my html section is two columns, but that the first column has two columns inside each other too.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOjLZ.png)

I try using grid row, grid column and flexbox.

One container, then the left grid column is 66%, and the right column is 33%.
See:

```
 <div class="grid"></div>
              <div class="grid__row"></div>
              <div class="grid__col grid__col--two-thirds">
                <div class="score">Laag 1: Bewustzijn</div>
                <div class="score">Laag 1: Bewustzijn</div>
                <div class="score">Laag 1: Bewustzijn</div>
                <div class="score">Laag 1: Bewustzijn</div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid__col">dfgkfdjglkfdjgkfdjglkfdjglkfdjglkfdjglkdfg</div>
```

And css:

```
.grid {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 16px;
    max-width: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid__row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.grid__col, .grid__spacer {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.grid__col--two-thirds {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 66.6667%;
    flex: 0 0 66.6667%;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work out.
What's an easy fix for this?

Comment: Try implementing CSS Grid. Refer: https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/create_a_website_layout.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used grids for solution. You can look codepen link.

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.container {
  width: 1000px; 
  margin: 30px auto; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 4, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  
  & > * {
    background-color: #FF7373;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding : 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  
}

.score1 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.score2 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.score3 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.score4 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.score5 {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.score6 {
   grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.score7 {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.score8 {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.score-box {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="score1"> Laag 1: Bewustzijn </div>
   <div class="score2"> Laag 2: Beleid </div>
   <div class="score3"> Laag 3: Monitoring </div>
   <div class="score4"> Laag 4: Data Security </div>
   <div class="score5"> Laag 5: Applicatie </div>
   <div class="score6"> Laag 6: EndPoint Security </div>
   <div class="score7"> Laag 7: netwerk/Systeem </div>
   <div class="score8"> Laag 8: Fysiek </div>
   <div class="score-box">dfgkfdjglkfdjgkfdjglkfdjglkfdjglkfdjglkdfg </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use display: flex. Then within these flexed boxes you can use more flexed boxes.

You can swap the flex direction to column to arrange the content vertically instead of horizontally, and align the items stretch to make the content equal in height or center to float the content in the center. If you pair all these things up you get your desired output.

Here's how I would do it:

```css
/* GENERAL */
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box!important;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  * {
   text-align: center;
  }
 }

 body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
/* END GENERAL */

.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1248px;
 margin: 0 auto; /* centers container */
 padding: 10px; /* this combined with the margin in the divs will make the margins appear consistent */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row; /* sort into rows */
 align-items: stretch;
 justify-content: space-between;
 text-align: center;
}

 .container .container-inner {
  width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
  margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */
  padding: 20px; /* space inside boxes */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* calculates border and padding in width */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row; /* sort into columns */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1; /* forces singular div that falls beneath to be full width */

  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 }
  @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
   .container .container-inner {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
   .container .container-inner {
    width: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   }
  }

  .container .container-col-one .container-content {
   width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */
   padding: 20px; /* space inside boxes */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* calculates border and padding in width */
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column; /* sort into columns */
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-grow: 1; /* forces singular div that falls beneath to be full width */

   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
   @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .container .container-inner {
     width: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
    }
   }
  .container .container-col-two .container-content {
   width: calc(100% - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */
   padding: 20px; /* space inside boxes */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* calculates border and padding in width */
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column; /* sort into columns */
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-grow: 1; /* forces singular div that falls beneath to be full width */

   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }

  h1 {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="container">

 <div class="container-col-one container-inner">
  <div class="container-content">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-content">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-col-two container-inner container-content">
  <div>
   <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

I have included some quick responsive tweaks too so you can get a grasp of how these can be pushed around.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can do that.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.grid__row {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background: pink;
}

.grid__col {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-width: 0;
}

.grid__col--two-thirds {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__row">Full Width Row</div>
  <div class="grid__col grid__col--two-thirds">
    <div class="score">Laag 1: Bewustzijn</div>
    <div class="score">Laag 2: Bewustzijn</div>
    <div class="score">Laag 3: Bewustzijn</div>
    <div class="score">Laag 4: Bewustzijn</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, dolorum?</div>
</div>
```